# Android - Get text from inflated layout Listview

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview in which I inflate a layout with multiple textviews and buttons. I understand to get the text from a view that was clicked is `((Textview)view...`. However I am trying to get the text from the specific textview that is located in the layout in which the user clicked. I have tried using OnItemClick but when I use this the item must be focused before the any of the buttons functions work. I resorted to and prefer using onClickListeners in the `getView` method of my custom adapter. So simply put, how do I click a Button and get the text that is in TextView that is located in the appropriate inflated layout list view item, given that since each inflated layout is considered as one list item?

Here are pictures to clarify what i am looking for. Both layouts are members of a listview. [image]

[image]

I want to click the button with the date on it and get the text from the textview in the middle of the layout. However when I click the button with the date on it, I can only get the text from the textview in the middle of the layout of the last child. If "My Party" is the first child in the listview and "3303 going away service..." is the second child, when I click the date button the code in my custom adapter returns the text from the last loaded text in the view which will be "3303 going away service". What I am trying to do is when I click the date button on "My party", get the text "My party". Like wise with the second child.

Here is the getView() in my custom adapter.

```
 @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

        positionHolder = position;
        Log.i("Position", "" + position);

        if(convertView == null) {

            try {

                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.post_layout, parent, false);
                postLayout = convertView;

                viewHolder.unameTV = (TextView) postLayout.findViewById(R.id.postUnameTv);
                viewHolder.unameTV.setText(viewContent.get(index));
                viewHolder.unameTV.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        // Starting new intent
                        Intent in = new Intent(getActivity(),
                                Profile.class);
                        // sending pid to next activity
                        String username =((TextView)view).getText().toString();
                        in.putExtra("username", username);

                        // starting new activity and expecting some response back
                        startActivityForResult(in, 100);
                    }
                });

                viewHolder.fillSpace = (TextView)postLayout.findViewById(R.id.posthelpSpace);
                viewHolder.fillSpace.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        viewHolder.unameTV.performClick();
                    }
                });




                viewHolder.image = (ImageView) postLayout.findViewById(R.id.postProfPic);
                DisplayImageOptions options = initiateDisplayImageOptions();
                viewHolder.image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        viewHolder.unameTV.performClick();
                    }
                });

                ImageLoader imageloader = ImageLoader.getInstance();

                initImageLoader(getActivity());
                imageloader.displayImage(viewContent.get(index + 1), viewHolder.image, options);




                viewHolder.addToCalendarButton = (TextView) postLayout.findViewById(R.id.addToCalendarButton);
                viewHolder.addToCalendarButton.setText(viewContent.get(index + 2));
                viewHolder.addToCalendarButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
                        cal.setTime(new Date());
                        cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 2);
                        long time = cal.getTime().getTime();

                        Uri.Builder builder =
                                CalendarContract.CONTENT_URI.buildUpon();
                        builder.appendPath("time");
                        builder.appendPath(Long.toString(time));
                        Intent intent =
                                new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT, CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI);

                        title = testText.getText().toString();
                        Log.i("Title", "" + title);
                        intent.putExtra("title", title); // **NOT WORKING**
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });



                viewHolder.eventTitle = (TextView) postLayout.findViewById(R.id.postTitleTV);
                viewHolder.eventTitle.setText(viewContent.get(index + 3));
                viewHolder.eventTitle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        title = ((TextView)view).getText().toString();
                        Log.i("TITLE", "" + title);

                    }
                });

                testText = viewHolder.eventTitle;
                viewHolder.eventImage = (ImageView) postLayout.findViewById(R.id.eventImage);
                imageloader.displayImage(viewContent.get(index + 4), viewHolder.eventImage, options);


                viewHolder.likesTV = (TextView) postLayout.findViewById(R.id.likesTV);
                viewHolder.likesTV.setText("" + viewContent.get(index + 5));

                viewHolder.planToAttendTV = (TextView) postLayout.findViewById(R.id.planToAttendTV);
                viewHolder.planToAttendTV.setText(viewContent.get(index + 6));

                viewHolder.addressTV = (TextView) postLayout.findViewById(R.id.postLocationTV);
                viewHolder.addressTV.setText("" + viewContent.get(index + 7));


                index = index + 8;


            }
            catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ie)
            {
                ie.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) postLayout.getTag();
        }




        return postLayout;
    }
```

**UPDATE**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
android:background="@drawable/fill_back"
>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:id="@+id/postUnameTv"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:gravity="center|center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="#ff518eff"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/postProfPic"
        android:text="Joshua" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Public"
        android:id="@+id/postProfileIcon"
        android:background="@drawable/publicicon"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="70dp"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/postProfPic"
        android:layout_below="@+id/postUnameTv"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="330dp"
        android:id="@+id/eventImage"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/space"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="20px"
        android:layout_height="20px"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/postProfPic"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
        android:id="@+id/space" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="20px"
        android:layout_height="20px"
        android:layout_above="@+id/postProfPic"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/space2" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:id="@+id/postTitleTV"
        android:layout_below="@+id/postProfPic"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="117dp"
        android:gravity="center|center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="28dp"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
        android:background="@drawable/details_button"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:id="@+id/postLocationTV"
        android:layout_below="@+id/postProfPic"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/locate_button"
        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
        android:gravity="clip_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/space"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:id="@+id/addToCalendarButton"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/postLocationTV"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/add_to_cal_button"
        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageButton3"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="2 hours ago"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:textSize="8dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:textColor="#ff828084"
        android:layout_above="@+id/eventImage"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/postProfPic"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/posthelpSpace"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/space"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/postProfPic"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/postProfPic" />

</RelativeLayout>

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/likeButton"
    android:background="@drawable/like_button_unsel"
    android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    />


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:id="@+id/likesTV"
    android:textColor="#ffe11100"

    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/likeButton"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/likeButton"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/likeButton"
    android:gravity="center|center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0.3dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/likeButton"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:background="@drawable/divider" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:id="@+id/planToAttendTV"
    android:layout_below="@+id/likesTV"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:text="Yes"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:textSize="10dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
    android:background="@drawable/border_circular"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/planToAttendTV"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:text="No"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:textSize="10dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button"
    android:background="@drawable/border_circular"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="Are you attending?"
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/likeButton"
    android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    />
```

Comment: You should definitively simplify *a lot* your code and your issue if you want some help

Comment: @SimonMarquis Well my issue is actually very simple but its hard to explain. Basically how do i get text from another textview that is the child of a listview?

Comment: How do you decide wich child of the listview to pick?

Comment: Thats my point. How do I decide that? I am trying to figure that out. The user selects the button in a child in the listview and I am trying to determine the appropriate textview to get the text from based off of the button in the child that of the listview that the user selected.

Comment: Post the xml of a child of your listview

Comment: I posted it. It is in the update

Comment: From your onClickListener (of the corresponding button) you can search your textView with : `((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_to_pick)).getText().toString()`

Comment: I just attempted that way again however that returns the text in the last child of the listview. Not the appropriate text.

Comment: I'm sure you are going wrong with all these onClickListener. The method I exposed you is functionnal. Simplify your code first.

Comment: @superuserdo are they displayed in the listView?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend making the child its own layout as a list item. I would then create a custom list view adapter which would make your layout much simpler as well as being able to get the text from the specific item clicked without having to worry about repeated code.

Answer (score 0):

Allright I guess I figured out what you are trying to get. Correct me If I'm wrong.

Normally, the idea of using custom adapter is based on List of Objects. You need to store all the information you have in an Object and create an ArrayList of those objects.

Then, whichever child you click in the list view, you will get the clicked child's index. This index is also the index of Object in your ArrayList.

After you know which index is clicked, then you can simply get the Object from your ArrayList with this index.

e.g If the 1st list item is clicked, the position you will get is "0", then you will need to use `yourArrayList.get(0).getTheDataYouWant()`